# Angular 2 Match/Merge/Push and Update Json

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ionic2

Using Angular 2 (and Ionic 2), I need to combine the different arrays into a sort of master list, to make it easy for the front end to display and manipulate all of the data correctly.

In other words, push the correct ID'd record into a new Users array with the name or values from Departments and Custom_fields. Both arrays to be merged in will be custom from the users, and not standardized.

#### Initial Server Response

```js
{
   "departments":[
      {
         "id":0,
         "name":"Staff"
      },
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Sales"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Development"
      }
   ],
   "custom_fields":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Company"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Job"
      }
   ],
   "users":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "email":"email@domain.com",
         "fname":"User",
         "lname":"One",
         "department":2,
         "custom_fields":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "value":"ABC Company"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "value":"Designer"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "email":"email2@domain.com",
         "fname":"User",
         "lname":"Two",
         "department":3,
         "custom_fields":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "value":"ABC Company"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "value":"President"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

#### Potential Client Side Example

Note the department_name and custom_fields.name added.

```js
   "users":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "email":"email@domain.com",
         "fname":"User",
         "lname":"One",
         "department":2,
         "department_name":"Development",
         "custom_fields":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"Company",
               "value":"ABC Company"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "name":"Job",
               "value":"Designer"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "email":"email2@domain.com",
         "fname":"User",
         "lname":"Two",
         "department":3,
         "custom_fields":[
            {
               "id":1,
               "name":"Company",
               "value":"ABC Company"
            },
            {
               "id":2,
               "name":"Company",
               "value":"President"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm using Ionic 3.0.1 and Angular 4.0.0 connecting over a websocket. Server response is fairly set in stone, but I'm totally open to any solution on the client side.

These records are separated so any updates can be done in a VERY small broadcast from the server, but therefore adding more work client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array#map](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) combine with [Array#find](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to build your data

```js
var json = {
       "departments":[
          {
             "id":0,
             "name":"Staff"
          },
          {
             "id":1,
             "name":"Sales"
          },
          {
             "id":2,
             "name":"Development"
          }
       ],
       "custom_fields":[
          {
             "id":1,
             "name":"Company"
          },
          {
             "id":2,
             "name":"Job"
          }
       ],
       "users":[
          {
             "id":1,
             "email":"email@domain.com",
             "fname":"User",
             "lname":"One",
             "department":2,
             "custom_fields":[
                {
                   "id":1,
                   "value":"ABC Company"
                },
                {
                   "id":2,
                   "value":"Designer"
                }
             ]
          },
          {
             "id":2,
             "email":"email2@domain.com",
             "fname":"User",
             "lname":"Two",
             "department":3,
             "custom_fields":[
                {
                   "id":1,
                   "value":"ABC Company"
                },
                {
                   "id":2,
                   "value":"President"
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    };

    var users = json.users;
    users.map(user => {
      var departmentName = json.departments.find(d => d.id == user.department);

      if (departmentName) {
       user.department_name = departmentName.name;
      }
      
       //Asume that custom_fields array are sorted by Id
       user.custom_fields = user.custom_fields.map((custom, idx) => {
          
          if (custom.id == json.custom_fields[idx].id) {
            custom.name = json.custom_fields[idx].name;
          }
          
          return custom;
       });
      return user;
    })

    console.log(users);
```

Comment: Very nice. Note: you can use `return {...custom, ...json.custom_fields[idx]};` instead of `Object.assign` which also won't mutate the original object.

Comment: That's not quite what I meant. I meant you can literally replace `return Object.assign(custom, json.custom_fields[idx]);` with `return {...custom, ...json.custom_fields[idx]};` by using the spread operator. Just a suggestion, original code was good too

Comment: After fighting with Typescript for a bit, Tai's unedited post actually worked. The edited custom field function only worked on records with all custom fields present. The original works for any situation. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at / can you make use of Underscore.js?

If so, then I would use the extend function:

> extend_.extend(destination, *sources)  Copy all of the properties in
>   the source objects over to the destination object, and return the
>   destination object. It's in-order, so the last source will override
>   properties of the same name in previous arguments.

```
_.extend({name: 'moe'}, {age: 50});
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}
```

In your case, if the first JSON block is stored in arrayOne, and the second JSON block is stored in arrayTwo, then you could do something like this (assuming the changed data is always in arrayOne.users, and the second array is always just the nested users object.

```
  public arrayMerge = _.extend(this.arrayOne.users, this.arrayTwo);
```

I've just done a quick test and it looks like it merges properly, but there's a little extra shrapnel and I'm not sure if that's to do with some overlap on your data or something I've done in wiring up the test jig.

If Underscore.js is an option this might do what you need. (I use it in my Angular2 projects, so let me know if you have any trouble integrating it).

Comment: Underscore was easy to add to the app, but my code to merge the records never got the intended results. I'll probably use Underscore in another function however. Thanks for your time.